# Deploy application to root domain instead of subdomain, using Caprover

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly, caprover

Hopefully this is a newbie Caprover question.
I have created a new app under "Apps" and I am trying to deploy my .Net Core application to it.

[image]

When I try to run the caprover deploy command, I can select the new "app" that I have created.
How can I change the application to point to `https://www.instatranscribe.com`(instead of `https://app.instatranscribe.com`) i.e deploy the application to the root domain instead of the subdomain?

Comment: According to the [docs](https://caprover.com/docs/get-started.html#step-4-deploy-the-test-app), _“[y]ou can connect multiple custom domains (like www.my-app.com) to a single app and enable HTTPS and do much more in the app's settings page.”_

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you @poke for your input. I was able to fix the issue by changing the app name from `app` to `www`.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone finding this down the line, you *can* add the actual root domain (`www` is still a subdomain - just a very common one).

Simply click "Add domain" and enter the root domain with no subdomain. You will need to ensure your root domain DNS record is pointed to the server's IP address.